# MySQL stored procedure doesn't return value

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

It works if I enter a value different. it  returned me value of message text "That ebook doesnt exists"

If I put exact value that is on my database it only execute but no return any value . Why?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SPBus ( 
        IN BUS VARCHAR (20)
    )  
    BEGIN

    START TRANSACTION;
    IF  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Ebook WHERE TituloEbook LIKE CONCAT('%',BUS,'%' )) THEN
       SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
       SET MESSAGE_TEXT= 'That ebook doesnt exists';
    ELSE 
        SELECT * FROM Ebook WHERE TituloEbook LIKE CONCAT('%',BUS, '%');
    END IF;
    COMMIT;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because then the procedure's else case will be executed where you are not setting `MESSAGE_TEXT`. Try this one:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SPBus ( 
        IN BUS VARCHAR (20)
    )  
    BEGIN

    START TRANSACTION;
    IF  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Ebook WHERE TituloEbook LIKE CONCAT('%',BUS,'%' )) THEN
       SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
       SET MESSAGE_TEXT= 'That ebook doesnt exists';
    ELSE 
        SELECT * FROM Ebook WHERE TituloEbook LIKE CONCAT('%',BUS, '%');
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'That ebook exists';
    END IF;
    COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: that code it only says me "that ebook exists" but I want to see name of the ebook...

Comment: Then you should select the name into a variable and concatenate it to the message. See more about select into here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into.html

Comment: this is my table : CREATE TABLE Ebook (IdEbook INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, TituloEbook VARCHAR(100), Precio INT, Anopubli DATE, IdCategoria INT, Sinopsis TEXT, IdEditor INT, Autor VARCHAR (50), IdMisLibros INT);